# How to know when a page is finished loading?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Using a `selenium driver`, I need to know when page is finished loading.

When you navigate to a new page, selenium does that. However, I do a button click, and I need to know when the next page will be loaded.

Is there a way to do something like `wait_for_loading_complete`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think selenium has inbuilt solution for checking the page load.
But we can build a method to verify the same. Some examples are below but there may be many more depending on the context.

1st :

```
public void waitUntilPageLoaded(long timeoutSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//body")));
}
```

2nd :

```
    public void waitUntilPageLoaded(long timeoutSeconds) {    

        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadFinishedCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                                "return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                    }
                };
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutSeconds);
                wait.until(pageLoadFinishedCondition);
}
```

3rd :

```
public void waitUntilPageLoaded(int timeoutSeconds, By locator) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutSeconds).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    }
```

Comment: sorry i used java implementation, but should be easy to convert them to c#